# What is "water" in the context of the spell control water?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

What counts as water when casting the spell *control water*? I'm sure that the answer could be "that's up to the DM", but how does the DM justify this judgement? There's many ways to approach this question; here are a few examples:

- Chemically: in that anything that mostly composed of H20 counts as
  water. Muddy river, glacial ice, frozen lake, mist, fog, etc.
- Intuitively: in that anything that seems like water counts as water.
  It's liquid, mostly clear, you can swim in it and drink it, etc.
- Simplistic: where only liquid, mostly pure water counts as water.

Related question:
[What the heck is "freestanding water"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/109300/what-the-heck-is-freestanding-water/)

Spell information:
https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/control-water

Comment: If you are asking for clarification on the 'definition' of freestanding water for *control water*, isn't that what the related question you have in your body is asking? What are you asking that's not in that question? Or is your question more general and just "what counts as water?"

Comment: Also related and possibly dupe: [What are the limitations on Shape Water?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68423/what-are-the-limitations-on-shape-water/68434#68434)

Comment: Beyond being (I believe) a dupe of the linked question, I'm not  even sure this on is answerable as-is. " I'm sure that the answer could be "that's up to the DM", but how does the DM justify this judgement?" We can't tell you this because each DM will have their own justification (or maybe they feel they don't need any justification at all!). There's no way for us to convey the whole range of what any DM might think about the definition of "water" in spells at their table.