# What happens if you use the control water spell on a living creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters

So I was play testing a monster and it was made of water. The character I was using had the [*control water*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/control-water) spell so I am wondering what would happen if I was to use that spell on a living monster such as a [Water Elemental](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/water-elemental) or a Water Weird.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### The water in elementals is presumably not freestanding

Ok, this comes down to a reading and meaning of terms the game doesn't define, but *control water* requires the targeting of freestanding water:

> Until the spell ends, you control any freestanding water inside an area you choose that is a cube up to 100 feet on a side.

And if the water is bound up in an elemental or similar, it is not freestanding. For more on that, see: [What the heck is "freestanding water"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/109300/52137)

As such, the water in the elemental is ineligible as a target for *control water*.

Comment: Nice link! I was looking for a way to back up the "freestanding" bit and that answer does it quite well